# Saving a trained multi-input classification algorithm in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I developed a script that predicts probable tags for some text, based on previously manually tagged feedback. I used several online articles to help me (namely: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-30714b7819c5).

Because I want the probability for each tag, here's the code I used:

```
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(alpha=0.3, fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
    ])

predictions_en = {}
for category in categories_en:
    NB_pipeline.fit(all_x_en, en_topics[category])
    proba_en = NB_pipeline.predict_proba(pred_x_en)
    predictions_en[category] = proba_en[-1][-1]

preds_en = pd.DataFrame(predictions_en.items())
preds_en = preds_en.sort_values(by=[1], ascending=False)
preds_en = preds_en.reset_index(drop=True)
```

It works very well for my purposes: it returns a prediction for each possible tag. But my issue is that it retrains the algorithm every time I try to make a prediction. What I'd like to do is to train the algorithm in a script, save the trained algorithm, load it in another script where the prediction is made.

I'd like to be able to do this in script 1:

```
for category in categories_en:
    NB_pipeline.fit(all_x_en, en_topics[category])
```

And this in the other script:

```
for category in categories_en:
    proba_en = NB_pipeline.predict_proba(pred_x_en)
    predictions_en[category] = proba_en[-1][-1]
```

But I can't seem to make it work. It just gives me the same prediction when I try to separate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use `pickle` to serialize any python object including yours. So the simplest and fastest way to save your model is to just serialize it to a file, say `model.pickle`. This is done in the first part after you train your model. After that, all you have to do is to check if the file exists and deserialize it using `pickle` again.

This is a function that serializes python objects to files:

```py
import pickle

def serialize(obj, file):
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

This is a function that deserializes python objects from files:

```py
import pickle

def deserialize(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

After your done training, all you have to do is to call (if `NB_pipeline` is the object of your model):

```
serialize(NB_pipeline, 'model.pickle')
```

And when you have to load it and use it just call:

```
NB_pipeline = deserialize('model.pickle')
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue is that if I separate the training from the prediction, it doesn't seem to work. I tried this:
`
    for category in categories_en:
        model[category] = NB_pipeline.fit(all_x_en, en_topics[category])
    test_proba = model[category].predict_proba(pred_x_en)
`

It return the same value for each category.

It seems like the loop that does the training and prediction works well to produce one model per category, and provide a prediction for each model - but I can't seem to create one model per category, and then apply it separately to new text.

Comment: @DavidPepin Do you mean that you want to train a category on demand? That is to make it more clear, do you want for any given category, either see if it exists in your dictionary or not and if it does, then use it to make predictions and if it doesn't then train a new model for that category and save it in that dictionary?

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. I had to instantiate NB_pipeline within my loop for it to work. I can then use the loop to train the algorithm for each class, serialize with pickle. And then deserialize in another script, and get predictions for new content. Thanks a lot!

Comment: model_en = {}
    for category in categories_en:
        NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(alpha=0.3, fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
            ])
    NB_pipeline.fit(all_x_en, en_topics[category])
    model_en[category] = NB_pipeline
    serialize(categories_en, 'categories_en.pickle')
    
    model_en = deserialize('model_en.pickle')
    for category in categories_en:
        proba_en = model_en[category].predict_proba(pred_x_en)
        predictions_en[category] = proba_en[-1][-1]

Comment: How the heck am I supposed to show codes in comments... I tried the 4 spaces and it doesn't work...